# Go to PHP page (submit data) with duplicated buttons?

Tags: php, mysql

I am printing out values (rows) from a MySQL table with php and I have a button on each row. I want this button to go to another php page for some other data processing. The problem is I want to send the id number to that page because this table has a one to many relationship with another table using the id as the primary key (auto-increment) and the id in the other table (when I click the button it will go to another page and use this id to get the values from the other table as the foreign key). Just looking from some ideas/examples on the best way to go about and do this. Thanks!

Code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $firstName = $row['firstName'];
    $lastName = $row['lastName'];
    echo "<tr> <td>".$id."</td><td>".$firstName."</td><td>".$lastName."</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>View</button></td></tr>";
} 


Example:
1.        John       Doe       buttonishere
2.        Sally      Blah      buttonishere
```

Example explained:
So basically these are my records in the first table of my mysql db where the id is a primary key on auto_incr. If I click the button for john then I want to go to another php page by sending the id (POST??) to that page. That is all I want to do because then I can use that id for my other table. So how would I go about using this button to go to another php by sending the data (only the id) also accounting for that the buttons are duplicated. Well, they should all go to the same page but all pass in a different id (they're associated id). Hopefully this is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
echo "<tr> <td>".$id."</td><td>".$firstName."</td><td>".$lastName."</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' onclick='location.href=\"otherpage.php?id=".$row['id']."\"'>View</button></td></tr>";
```

In `otherpage.php`, you will have to use `$_GET['id']` in order to know the id.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick answer! Does $_GET['id'] get the id from the url?

Comment: @shapiro yes, user will be redirected to otherpage.php?id=<id>

Comment: ahh sorry I'm a little confused. How would I set up the name of the php page so it knows to always go there but with the different id. Would it just be "otherpage.php"

Comment: Yes, you can name it "otherpage.php" (or with any name you want, of course). The part after the "?" of an url doesn't represent the filename.
Each button of the table brings to otherpage.php, but provides a different id

Comment: Happy I could help :) I've built a demo so you can try it out: [click here](http://stubborn.altervista.org/tests/get.php) to see it